# Usage of "as because"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I would like to know if "as because" is a correct usage. It feels so wrong, yet I see people using it.
e.g. She couldn't come, as because she was ill.

I suppose only because should serve the purpose here.

Comment: I've never actually heard that phrase used before. What kind of dialect? Where are you from?

Comment: I am from India, and I see people using it here. I find it very odd, I don't know why.

Comment: I know why - because it is odd! I have never heard that usage, even in SEA.

Answer (score 1):

*As*, *for*, *because*, and *due to (the fact that)* all mean *the reason being*. Therefor, "as because" is needlessly repetitive.

> - She couldn't come, as she was ill.
> - She couldn't come, because she was ill.
> - She couldn't come, for she was ill.
> - She couldn't come, due to the fact that she was ill.

However, "correctness" is a snare. Let's just say that only one of them is necessary to get your point across. And, it sounds funny/odd to native English speakers to use both when one alone is customary.

Comment: And that using 'as because' in place of 'as' or 'because' sounds somewhere along the odd ... weird ... unacceptable cline to native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

As medica mentioned, saying "as because" is redundant, and as I mentioned in the comment above it's not something that's really said in American English. For anyone who didn't see the comment, the original poster is speaking of an Indian dialect.

I picture this as being kind of like the phrase "kind of like." Both words mean the same, but it's used to provide an extra abstract example, or almost to disclaim the applicability of what's about to be said. It's kind of a word stumble type of thing used in casual conversation. I think this and "as because" might fall under the same type of usage.

As odd as the phrase sounds to me personally, I can picture someone saying "I can't make it to work today as I'm... because I'm... uh.. sick"

Usage of the phrase "as because" might have its roots in slightly different cultural interpretations of the word "as." We could assume that "as" in this context is meant to mean "this is." In American English, only specific sentence structures give the word "as" that meaning, but it may have become more of a catch-all over there than it is over here.

Comment: Why is 'American' capitalised but 'English' not?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for catching that. If you're really interested in why I default to lower case for a blatant noun, here's an interesting one: I've been writing software since before I knew how to write coherent sentences well. My mind treats almost everything I do as a programming language. (When I write, I'm just programming paper. Right?) In programming, there's types of data: Text, numbers, true/false logic. I process "English" as a programming datatype, and "American" is a variable. I never capitalize datatypes. See also POSIX locales, where `en_US` is how we say American English

Comment: But this is an English language website, not a computer website. When in Rome ...

Comment: I was asked why, I answered why, and I edited the post to be correct. No need to be rude, Mr. Ashworth. I shared a bit of lexical psychology which I assumed a scholar would find mildly interesting. Had I known I surely wouldn't have wasted my time rationalizing to a rhetorical question, @EdwinAshworth.

Comment: I'm merely paraphrasing / referring to the requirements given in the Help Center here for acceptable grammar and punctuation when answering. I believe that doesn't constitute rudeness.